# MSBuild references not copied

Tags: reference, msbuild

Consider the following setup:

```
ProjectA
    References
        Foo
        Bar
```

ProjectA uses in his code only static references to Foo, not Bar, this one is only opened through reflection.

Then we have ProjectB

```
ProjectB
    References
        ProjectA
```

Compiling this with MSBuild yields the ProjectA.dll and Foo.dll in ProjectB's output folder.

However, is there a way that I can tell MSBuild (VS seems to do this by default) that I also need Bar.dll, without adding Bar to the references of ProjectB?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a couple days ago. The solution that I found was to create a dummy class that instantiates an object from Bar in ProjectA. This should then generate the Bar.dll. I don't know why Msbuild works like this but it does. Does anyone know a better solution?